# I Cant quite get java3d working, cant importe files

Tags: java, jar, java-3d

*Im trying to get the java 3d librarys to work with my project in InteliJ,
I have downloaded the java3d files from the oracle page (1.5.1). Somewhere
in the internet I got told those are the old ones and downloaded the 1.7
version of the .jar files(j3dcore.jar, j3dexamples.jar, j3ddutils.jar,
vecmath.jar). Where I'm stuck right now is that I know I i have to add
the files as external files. I went to files-projects structe-modules
and added all 4 .jar files but when I try to import it still does not
work, under Project structures I also tried
to add the . jar files from the libraris tabthingy but with no rezults.
The files I got from Oracle are under C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\lib\ext and the ones in donwload on the interner are under C:\Users\OnLine\Desktop\jogamp-java3d (1)
. Right now I have the jar files from dekstop on my project.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;

import j3d.utils.universe.*;
import j3d.utils.geometry.*;

import java.applet.*;

import j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
public class ConeAndSphere extends Applet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame(new ConeAndSphere(), 640, 480);
    }

    public void init() {
        // create canvas
        GraphicsConfiguration gc =
                SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph();
        bg.compile();
        SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
        su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        su.addBranchGraph(bg);
    }

    private BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
        {
            BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
            TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
            spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
            root.addChild(spin);
            // deri qitu osht 100% nisoj si en liber
        }

        // primitives
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        ap.setMaterial(new Material());
        //deri qitu - si m'liber
        //-----------------------
        //e ka bo ni kub dhe ni kon
        Box cube = new Box(1f, 1f, 1f, ap);
        Cone cone = new Cone();

        Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
        tr.setScale(0.2);
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
        spin.addChild(tg);
        // si nliber

        tr.setIdentity();
        tr.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0f, 1.5f, 0f));
        TransformGroup tgCube = new TransformGroup(tr);
        tg.addChild(tgCube);
        tgCube.addChild(cube);

        TransformGroup tgCylinder = new TransformGroup(tr);
        tg.addChild(tgCylinder);
        tr.setTranslation(new Vector3f(1f, -1.5f, 0f));
        TransformGroup tgCone = new TransformGroup(tr);
        tg.addChild(tgCone);
        tgCone.addChild(cone);

        {
            //first number number of rotations
            Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, 5000);
            RotationInterpolator rotator =
                    new RotationInterpolator(alpha, spin);
            BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
            rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
            spin.addChild(rotator);
            // si nliber


            // background and light
            Background background = new Background(100.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
            root.addChild(background);
            AmbientLight light =
                    new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(Color.blue));
            light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
            root.addChild(light);
            PointLight ptlight = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.green),
                    new Point3f(3f, 3f, 3f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
            ptlight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
            root.addChild(ptlight);
            PointLight ptlight2 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.red),
                    new Point3f(-2f, 2f, 2f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
            ptlight2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
            root.addChild(ptlight2);
            return root;
            // drrita krejt si en liber
            // nashta ngjyrat viq i ka ndrru
        }
    }
}
```

*h [how my screen looks rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LhkO.png)*
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL5x5.png)

*Thank you for your time *

Comment: Belive it or not after 2 days this video fixed it. Just create a directory on the project file and store the .jar files in there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAJ09o3Xl_0

Comment: Java3D 1.5.1 is completely obsolete and unmaintained, you should use a more up-to-date version of Java3D. Be aware that Java3D 1.7 uses a different package namespace, not "javax.media". Moreover, applet support has been removed from Java, it's absent of Java 11 which is the latest LTS version, I advise you not to use it. The video you quote explains how to include a third party library in IntelliJ, it's not specific to Java3D, my tutorial explains how to use it: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/